# Does aria-hidden need a value?

Tags: html, accessibility

Can I do `<div aria-hidden>` instead of `<div aria-hidden="true">` or should I always do `<div aria-hidden="true">`?

Comment: [aria-hidden](https://www.w3.org/WAI/PF/aria/states_and_properties#aria-hidden)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The current version of spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#aria-hidden) indicates that "aria-hidden" is a state, and it could have three values:

> **false**: The element is exposed to the accessibility API as if it was rendered.
>
> **true**: The element is hidden from the accessibility API.
>
> **undefined (default)**: The element's hidden state is determined by the user agent based on whether it is rendered.

This means that when `aria-hidden` attribute is set on an element without an explicit true or false value, it will be considered hidden if it is not rendered.

> Can I do `<div aria-hidden>` instead of `<div aria-hidden="true">` or should I always do `<div aria-hidden="true">`?

`<div aria-hidden>` and `<div aria-hidden="true">` are not equivalent, and you must set `aria-hidden="true"` if the element is visible on screen but you wish to hide it from the accessibility API.

Comment: The default value is "undefined" https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#aria-hidden . I don't see in your answer an evidence for stating that an empty value would not replace the "true" value as for any boolean attributes. The right answer (see @Quentin) is that `aria-hidden` is not a boolean attribute but a state (as it can have 3 different values)

Comment: @Adam Thanks for pointing out. I was looking at an older version of the spec. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

It is not a boolean attribute. An explicit value must be provided.

Comment: This is the correct answer. `aria-hidden` is a state and can have 3 values : true, false and "undefined".

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `aria-hidden="true"` (or `false`, respectively).

A comment on `aria-hidden="false"`, though: As far as I can tell, this doesn't have a useful effect. `display:none;` will still render content invisible for screen readers, even when `aria-hidden` is set to `false`, so it's NOT a way of dragging elements out of invisibility for screen readers.

Please note that using `aria-hidden` should be considered carefully: Depending on the browser used, unexpected effects can occur. As `aria-hidden` marks an element and all its child elements as hidden, but might not negate other attributes, you need to test your UIs thoroughly when using `aria-hidden`. For example, a child element might be focusable, but marked as hidden -- focus still moves to that element, but no accessibility information is rendered, because that element is supposed to be hidden.